# Are there any dua's to help getting married to someone?

Tags: nikah, dua

I want to get married soon. I have a person whom I want to get married to. But my parents are not allowing  as they don’t like the guy.  They think he is not the right choice and never even talked to him for once to know about him. They just presumed. But I think he is a good human and the delay in marriage is causing excessive stress for me.

**How do I pray to Allah (SWT)  so that I can marry the person I want to? Is there any dua for it?**

Thank you

Comment: Peace Humayra, is this person you want to marry a believer? Example http://free-minds.org/mumins

Comment: I don't understand the issue nor why you are stressed based on talking to a stranger once: as long as this guy didn't do the first step by asking for your hand all you both do is illegal and he didn't show any sincere interest in marrying you in a legal manner which makes his intentions doubtful. Also just talking once is not enough to get to know him. And at the end your parents know best what is good for you and they want your best.

Comment: @rahi. Assalamualaikum. Yes the person is a muslim.

Comment: @Medi1Saif he did ask for my hand. His parents called my parents with the marriage proposal. And I know him for more than a year. It’s not that I talked once only and he is not a stranger. I know every parents wants the best for their children but at but it’s equally important to understand what children wants. And I just want to make dua to Allah(SWT) so that I can get married to the person I want to .

Comment: This information was not in your post, we can only answer based on the given information.

Answer (score 0):

Salaam . Bismillah.

You can make any dua you want, a sincere and private conversation with God is your prerogative anytime you're able to call to God. You might benefit from asking for sabr as suggested in 4:25.

> And who from you is not able to reach to marry the protected women, so marry from what your oath possesses from your immature/(family protected) believing women, and God is more knowing about your belief. You are from one another, so marry them with their families' permission, and give them their rewards with kindness, protected, not fornicating, and not taking multiple takers. So when they become self-protected (through marriage), if they commit illegal sexual activity, on them is half the punishment of the (already) self-protected, that is for those who feared corruption from you, **and being patient is better for you**, and God is forgiving, merciful.

This translation is by *The Monotheist Group*. Other translations of this ayat can be found [here](https://www.islamawakened.com/quran/4/25/default.htm).

As it relates to the disagreement you had with your parents, here are some questions you might need to consider carefully, ideally, *before* acting out of urgency

- Do you consider yourself to still be under the guardianship (or 'protection') of your parents?

  - If yes, then ayat 4:25 urges you to *not marry* against their wishes as the family's permission seems to be needed.
  - If no, in other words, if you're mature and manage all of your life's affairs, and you are not under the guardianship of your parents, then you don't need your parent's consent per se (according to ayat 4:25)
  - There's more about this topic [here](https://www.free-minds.org/rules-engagement).
- Is the topic of getting engaged to this guy an option? Or is the topic closed?

  - If yes, getting engaged is a possibility, then you might opt for that without finalizing the marriage, yet. This way both you and your family can evaluate the suitability of your match.
  - If your parents have vetoed this guy outright *and* you're still under their guardianship, then it's likely wiser to respect their decision
  - God knows best. So just believe in God, perform salaat and endure your situation with patience (sabr). God is aware of your plight, and is listening and answering according to ayat [2:186](https://www.free-minds.org/quran/PM/2/186).